# Symbolic matrix addition in R

Tags: r

I want to add two matrix P and Q symbolically in R. I have written this using "rSymPai" library function.Then how can I find X which is equal to P + Q.

```
    P<-matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:2){
  for (j in 1:2) {
    P[i,j] = paste0("P", i, j) 
  }
}
P
Q<-matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:2){
  for (j in 1:2) {
    Q[i,j] = paste0("Q", i, j) 
  }
}
Q
```

Comment: The library is called "rSym**Py**"

Answer (score 0):

The package 'rSymPy' is just a wrapper to Python's SymPy package. [This is the documentation for matrices](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html).

You want the following code in Python/SymPy (try it with [SymPy live](http://live.sympy.org/)):

```
P = Matrix([['P1','P2'],['P3','P4']])
Q = Matrix([['Q1','Q2'],['Q3','Q4']])
Result = P + Q
```

In R, the rSymPy's function `sympy(...)` takes Python code as string, so you want to generate the following strings in R:

```
"P = Matrix([['P1','P2'],['P3','P4']])"
"Q = Matrix([['Q1','Q2'],['Q3','Q4']])"
```

You can generate this strings from the variable `P` and `Q` in your question by R string manipulation. Afterwards, you should be able to use them with the R `sympy` function (couldn't test the last three lines, as I have no Python and SymPy installed on this machine)

```
library(rSymPy)
# Copied from Question
P<-matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:2){
  for (j in 1:2) {
    P[i,j] = paste0("P", i, j) 
  }
}
P
##      [,1]  [,2] 
## [1,] "P11" "P12"
## [2,] "P21" "P22"
Q<-matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:2){
  for (j in 1:2) {
    Q[i,j] = paste0("Q", i, j) 
  }
}
Q
##      [,1]  [,2] 
## [1,] "Q11" "Q12"
## [2,] "Q21" "Q22"
# -----------------------------------
makeSymPyMatrix <- function(name, mat){
  dim <- dim(mat) # needed to restore matrix dimensions
  # Add the single quotes
  mat <- Q
  mat <- sub('(.*)',"'\\1'",mat)
  # Add the inner commas
  mat <- apply(mat, 1, function(row){paste(row, collapse = ',')})
  # Add the inner brackets
  mat <- sub('(.*)',"[\\1]",mat)
  # Add the outer commas
  mat <- paste(mat, collapse = ',')
  # Add the outer brackets
  mat <- sub('(.*)',"[\\1]",mat)
  # Add the Matrix function
  mat <- sub('(.*)',"Matrix(\\1)",mat)
  return(mat)
}
# See what this function returns
makeSymPyMatrix(P)
## "Matrix([['P11','P12'],['P21','P22']])"
Pvar <- sympy(makeSymPyMatrix(P))
Qvar <- sympy(makeSymPyMatrix(Q))
Pvar + Qvar
```